# Empty array in an array of arrays is skipped?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I have stumbled upon a case I have never had before. I have an array of arrays and each array has several objects inside or nothing inside.

I use the objects to generate some HTML and all works well except when I try to handle the empty data (an array that has no objects inside). I was thinking to loop through them and if I get an array that is empty to create specific HTML but I just can't seem to handle it... maybe it sounds confusing when I explain like this, so I will leave the code snippet talk for itself

```js
const theGrandArray = [
  [
    {id:1},
    {id:12},
    {id:13}
  ],
  [
    {id:2},
    {id:22},
    {id:23}
  ],
  [], // this is the array I want to handle
  [
    {id:4},
    {id:42},
    {id:43}
  ]
]
const theUl = document.getElementById('theUl')
for(let i = 0; i < theGrandArray.length; i++ ){
  for(let k = 0; k < theGrandArray[i].length; k++){
    if(!theGrandArray[i][k].id){
      console.log('ahaaa!')
    }
    let liElement = document.createElement('li')
    liElement.innerText = theGrandArray[i][k].id
    theUl.appendChild(liElement)
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="theUl"></ul>
```

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is; if you want to handle an empty nested array check for its length, if `0` do one thing, of `> 0` do what you're doing now (or whatever it is you need to do).

Comment: It doesn't work because `k < theGrandArray[i].length` is always false with the empty array. `theGrandArray[i].length` is `0` and `0 < 0` is false.

Comment: Just a suggestion, using a `forEach` loop might help you see more clearly and debug accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to debug it? Chrome Dev Tools might come in handy.
Your innermost `for` code will never execute for the empty sub-array, because `theGrandArray[2].length` is zero. To handle that case you want to add e.g. an `if` before that `for`:

```
if (theGrandArray[i].length === 0) { 
  /* special case */
} else {
  for (/* ... */)
}
```

Comment: Silly me, guess my brain has really melted after 8 hours of work on monday =D

Comment: Yes, sometimes all you need is a fresh look :D

Answer (score 1):

You could use [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on the parent array and [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the inner ones:

```js
theGrandArray.forEach(arr => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerText = arr.map(el => el.id).join(', ')
  theUl.appendChild(li);
})
```

See it here:

```js
const theGrandArray = [
  [
    {id:1},
    {id:12},
    {id:13}
  ],
  [
    {id:2},
    {id:22},
    {id:23}
  ],
  [], // this is the array I want to handle
  [
    {id:4},
    {id:42},
    {id:43}
  ]
]
const theUl = document.getElementById('theUl')
theGrandArray.forEach(arr => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerText = arr.map(el => el.id).join(', ')
  theUl.appendChild(li);
})
```

```html
<ul id="theUl"></ul>
```

If you want to provide some fallback content when there are no items, you could check the inner array's `length`:

```js
theGrandArray.forEach(arr => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerText = arr.length
    ? arr.map(el => el.id).join(', ')
    : 'No data...';
  theUl.appendChild(li);
})
```

```js
const theGrandArray = [
  [
    {id:1},
    {id:12},
    {id:13}
  ],
  [
    {id:2},
    {id:22},
    {id:23}
  ],
  [], // this is the array I want to handle
  [
    {id:4},
    {id:42},
    {id:43}
  ]
]
const theUl = document.getElementById('theUl')
theGrandArray.forEach(arr => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerText = arr.length
    ? arr.map(el => el.id).join(', ')
    : 'No data...';
  theUl.appendChild(li);
})
```

```html
<ul id="theUl"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is an IF condition to decide what to do when you encounter an empty array:

```js
const theGrandArray = [
  [
    {id:1},
    {id:12},
    {id:13}
  ],
  [
    {id:2},
    {id:22},
    {id:23}
  ],
  [], // this is the array I want to handle
  [
    {id:4},
    {id:42},
    {id:43}
  ]
]
const theUl = document.getElementById('theUl')

for(let i = 0; i < theGrandArray.length; i++ ){
  
  if (theGrandArray[i].length !== 0){
    for(let k = 0; k < theGrandArray[i].length; k++){
      if(!theGrandArray[i][k].id){
        console.log('ahaaa!')
      }
      let liElement = document.createElement('li')
      liElement.innerText = theGrandArray[i][k].id
      theUl.appendChild(liElement)
    }
  }
  else {
      let liElement = document.createElement('li')
      liElement.innerText = '---- no data ----';
      theUl.appendChild(liElement)
  }
     
  
  
  
}
```

```html
<ul id="theUl"></ul>
```